# wordpress カテゴリー別アーカイブページで投稿数を取得して表示させる

Tags: php, wordpress

wordpressでカテゴリー別アーカイブページでカテゴリー別に投稿総数を取得し表示させたいのですが、

```
<?php 
    $post_count = wp_count_posts()->publish; 
    echo $post_count;
?>
```

上記のコードだどすべての投稿数を取得して表示してしまうと思います。

```
<?php 
    $news_post_count = wp_count_posts('news')->publish; 
    echo $news_post_count;
?>
```

上記のコードでカテゴリーを指定して取得できるのですが、
カテゴリーアーカイブ出力ファイルはひとつなので、
複製してファイルを増やすなんて事はまずしないだろうと勝手に判断しています。

私が行いたいのは、
どのカテゴリーなのか識別を行い、そのカテゴリーのみの投稿総数をカテゴリータイトル（こちらも取得）と一緒に表示させたいのですが、私はPHPに詳しくないので自己解決に至りませんでした。

解決策をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご協力をお願い致します。

Comment: `wp_count_posts()` に指定するのはカテゴリではなく投稿タイプだという話を見かけたのですが、`news` は投稿タイプではないのでしょうか？ http://glow-factory.com/blog_wp/template-tag/wp-count-posts/

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。
newsに関しましては、内容を隠す為のフェイクで、実際はカテゴリーを記載しております。上記のコードでも表示されるのですが、今回はカテゴリーを取得して表示させる所で詰まっております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決いたしましたので、ご報告させていただきます。

カテゴリー名に関しましては、テーマに付属していたカテゴリー名取得のコードを利用しました。

カテゴリー数取得につきましては、 [`get_queried_object()`](http://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9/get_queried_object) で[カテゴリーオブジェクト](http://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0/get_the_category#.E8.BF.94.E3.81.95.E3.82.8C.E3.82.8B.E3.82.AA.E3.83.96.E3.82.B8.E3.82.A7.E3.82.AF.E3.83.88.E3.81.AE.E3.83.A1.E3.83.B3.E3.83.90.E3.83.BC.E5.A4.89.E6.95.B0)を取得することで以下のように書けました。

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
    $term = get_queried_object();
    echo ' カテゴリー数は ' . $term->count . ' 件です。';
?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

他にもっと効率的な方法などございましたら、ご教授いただけると幸いでございます。

取得・表示することはできましたので、解決済みとさせていただきます。

Comment: `get_queried_object()` とカテゴリーオブジェクトについてリンクを追加しました。

Answer (score 1):

> カテゴリー別アーカイブページでカテゴリー別に投稿総数を取得し表示させたい

「現在、ブラウザで表示しているカテゴリーアーカイブページに、そのカテゴリーに属する投稿数を表示する」という認識であっていますでしょうか？

現在表示しているカテゴリーアーカイブページのカテゴリーIDはグローバル変数 `$cat` にセットされているとのことですので、

```
<?php
$category = get_category( $cat );
$category_slug = $cat_info->slug;
$post_count = wp_count_posts( $category_slug )->publish;
echo $post_count;
?>
```

といったコードでいかがでしょうか。

動作確認は行っていませんので、動作しない場合は、一度、私の方でも動作確認を行ってみたいと思いますので、その旨コメントいただければと思います。

## 参考

[WordPress › フォーラム » category.phpで現在のカテゴリースラッグを表示したい](https://ja.forums.wordpress.org/topic/1708)

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。
上記コードを試してましたが、うまく表示されませんでした。